# facing an issue when update my target sdk 30 to 31 in android with react native

Tags: android, sdk

hope all doing good. I'm facing an issue with target sdk 30 when uploading my app to google console. Minimun target sdk required for google console is 31. How to update target sdk from 30 to 31[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTr06.jpg)

Comment: same issue. did you already resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Apps targeting **Android12/API 31 must explicitly declare android:exported** for all the activities, services and BroadcastReceivers whichever has an intent filter.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

Please check whether you have declared **android:exported** wherever needed. It can be declared in Manifest or in the respective file.